# Help binding a static objective-c library in monotouch

Tags: c#, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, static-libraries

I need help binding a static Obj-c library I created for use from within MonoTouch, using btouch.

I know the basic syntax when creating the API files, but I have functions in my library that I simply can't find the right way to bind :S

Here's how my header looks like:

```
- (UIImage*) functionSampleOne:(CGImageRef)srcCGImage;
- (UIImage*) functionSampleTwo:(CGImageRef)srcCGImage;
CGImageRef functionSampleThree(CGImageRef image);
```

What would the btouch api for this header look like? How do I bind UIImage* and CGImageRef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other object:

```
[Export("functionSampleOne:")]
UIImage FunctionSampleOne(CGImage srcImage);
```

Don't forget to add the appropriate namespaces in the API definition file:

```
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
```

Comment: That's exactly how I tried it the first time, it didn't work. BUT right now after you confirmed it is the right way, I found another bug in my code which actually caused the exception, so it works now! :) thanks! :)

Comment: Just a note. You should make sure that once it works in the simulator, that it works on the device. You may have to create a big fat static library for it to work on both. Unless, of course you build separate libs for each environment.